# JS: Test elements existence and tag name as a one liner

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dom, nodes, element

I am trying to find the correct a-tag within a DOM. For this I need to parse its direct neighbors:

```
let strongTags = document.querySelectorAll('div.entry p strong');
for (let i = 0; i < strongTags.length; i++) {
    if (strongTags[i].textContent.toLowerCase().match("size")) {
        let dbATag;
        if (strongTags[i].nextElementSibling) {
            if (strongTags[i].nextElementSibling.tagName == "A") {
                dbATag = strongTags[i].nextElementSibling;
            } else if (strongTags[i].nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling) {
                if (strongTags[i].nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.tagName == "A") {
                    dbATag = strongTags[i].nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I don't know if the a tag is in nextElementSibling or in the second nextElementSibling. Theoretically there could be a third one, but I never saw it in the data. I'd like something like a querySelector('a') directly from the strongTags[i] position within the current parent. But that's another one of my don't knows.

My current main problem is that I can't test if strongTags[i].nextElementSibling exists and if tagName is A, like this:

if (strongTags[i].nextElementSibling && strongTags[i].nextElementSibling.tagName == "A").

Even though it doesn't exist, the interpreter still tries to test for tagName as well. This results in an error that stops further execution of my script. That's why I split it into two lines for now.

How can I solve this a bit more beautiful? :)

EDIT:
I have no influence on DOM creation. I do page modification with Tampermonkey.

And I can not post the page itself. But I can post a part of DOM from the section if it helps:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="post">
        <h1 id="post-1243629">Post-Header</h2>
            <div class="entry">
                <p></p>
                <blockquote>
                    <p></p>
                    <p></p>
                </blockquote>
                <p><strong>Date: </strong>ddmmyyy / 
                    <strong>Format: </strong>$ / 
                    <strong>Optional strong tag: </strong>Data / 
                    <strong>Size: </strong>MB / 
                    <strong>Db:</strong><a href="">xyz</a>
                    <strong>Optional strong tag: </strong>Data /
                </p>
                <p><strong></strong><br />
                    <strong></strong> <a href=""></a><br />
                    <span>
                        <strong></strong> <a href=""></a><br />
                    </span>
                    <span id="">
                        <strong></strong> <a href=""></a><br />
                        <strong></strong> <a href=""></a><br />
                        <strong></strong> <a href=""></a><br />
                    </span>
                    <strong></strong>
                </p>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the html?

Comment: "More beautiful" is quite subjective. Maybe you can have a look at [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)?

Comment: Looks to me that what's missing is a class on the <a>tags; with that a simple `getElementsByClassname("myclass")` would do what you want in just a line or two. Is there no way to add a class to the anchors? Alternatively, try using jQuery, which has a richer set of DOM traversal methods.

Comment: `nextElementSibling` returns `null` when there is no sibling, and with `null` being _falsy_ in JS that _should_ short-circuit the `if()` statement. So I don't understand how you could get the error you claim.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Find all `<p>` elements which have a `<strong>` child and then find any `<a>` sibling of that child? You should probably edit your question and change the second `<p>` block to something that should not be selected, and then show your expected output.

Comment: Finding the a tag near the size tag. There could be a tags in the optional strong tags too. So not necessary only one a tag within the p node.